# R - how to programmatically get number of citations for a research article?

Tags: r, data-mining

For data mining research literature in R, is there a way to retrieve the number of citations for an article (assuming I have a pmid, doi, or some other article identifier)?

Comment: Pubmed has a number of citations entry??? (I'm skeptical.) Can you offer a link to documentation about that feature.

Comment: I don't necessarily have to use pubmed/rismed to get this information. any database I can query with using r would be fine

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've done so far?  I think this could be difficult.  ISI Web of Knowledge doesn't want to be scraped, [Google scholar doesn't want to be scraped and doesn't provide the information conveniently](http://bmb-common.blogspot.ca/2011/11/google-scholar-still-sucks.html) ... I think there might be some Scopus-based tools that would work ...

Comment: It's now clear that the questioner has no idea how to do this manually and so is asking for a recommendation for an outside tool.

Comment: I'd love to see some answers though ...

Comment: You probably need to **buy** this kind of API access.

Comment: re: offtopic - I'm not asking for a "recommended" answer - I'm asking if there's an answer at all.

Comment: daj, do you think that my answer is reproducible for what you want?

Comment: @rodrigo - appreciate the response but ideally I'd like an answer that's more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I came up with this:

```
#imagine the DOI is : 10.1097/PAI.0b013e3181ecaf1c
#so for google you need to substitute '/' for %2F

doi <- "10.1097/PAI.0b013e3181ecaf1c"
doi2 <- gsub("/", "%2F", doi)
thepage = readLines(paste('http://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q=', doi2, sep=""))

theDOI <- thepage[grep(paste('doi:', doi, "|Cited by", thepage)]
citedBy <- gregexpr("Cited by", theDOI)

n_of_citations <- lapply(1:length(theDOI), function(x){
    substr(x=theDOI[[x]], start=citedBy[[x]], stop=citedBy[[x]]+10)
})


#usualy on google the first match is the correct result search... so..
n_of_citations[[1]]

[1] "Cited by 23"
```

is based on google result. However, not all results have the citation numbers, and not always the first result on google is the correct result...

Comment: btw, this DOI was the last paper I've read... lol